# How would you achieve a LED Scrolling effect?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview, scroll

How would you achieve an LED Scrolling effect like the example below?

[LED Sign - LED Ticker emulator for the iPhone and iPad http://img.skitch.com/20101201-rsfh4p1bajb1wp94k466pdpiuj.preview.jpg](https://skitch.com/jordanx/rnijf/led-sign-led-ticker-emulator-for-the-iphone-and-ipad)

Comment: Hmmm ... I'll bite :) Treat the rows as a queue, bitmap chars in the message and pop columns onto the queue (and off the other end) in order ..

Comment: Or I'd go out and buy an LED scrollbar from tech-outlet-of-choice :)

Comment: It's "effect" by the way, not "affect" :-).

Comment: The string written in it is known a priori or dynamically inserted/computed?

Comment: The string is dynamically inserted, from field can be changed by user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sometimes it remunerates to comment in other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5597033/207616) :)

Have put some code together for you, but you should implement the font `'8Pin Matrix'` to get realistic feeling.

```
UILabel *label;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 20)];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier-Bold" size:16.0];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap; // otherwise you would get "…"
    label.text = @"This LED Text will be scrolled               "; // some blanks to get space between
    [self.view addSubview:label];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.12f target:self 
                                   selector:@selector(scrollLabel) 
                                   userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

- (void)scrollLabel {
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [label.text substringFromIndex:1], [label.text substringToIndex:1]];
}
```

Comment: you rock! I haven't tried it yet, but this is awesome! I don't know why I made it more complicated than it was ;)